# Partial Differentiation

Tags: partial, differentiation

I wanted to know command for differentiating a complex Function. I am having trouble formulating the function I want to partially differentiate with respect to Q and then get just optimal Q. fi,Xi, li, Yi ,Qfi and Qsi are the decision Variables. All of this is for ith supplier. One issue I am getting in multiplying 2 variables together for eg. fi*Sfi*Xi, how to do that?
[image]

Comment: Are you sure this is a programming question and not something better answered on [math.se]?

Comment: I think this is question for mathematics in stack exchange rather than overflow.   Beside I only see the output cost function but do not know what is the variable/ control input. in which paper and which section did you find it

Comment: Hi, Thank you for responding.I have rephrased my question. I started by writing just a fraction of the function like '''Cost= D*lpSum([F[i]*FSCF[i] for i in range(sup) + L[i]*FSCL[i]for i in range(sup)])''' But the moment I mutlipy with X(i), I get error 'Non-constant expressions cannot be multiplied'. I want to get optimal Q from Partial differentiation and then plug it into Cost to make it objective function and then minimize it. Here, is the link to the paper I am replicating (pg.13-14) https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/39f1/b3fdc66c3f890962ba921fabe6a4959bc915.pdf. Thanks in advance!